# How to remove a list from list in tcl

Tags: list, tcl

I have two lists

- set a1 {a b c d e f}
- set b1 {b f e}

I am trying to do remove_from_list  `$a1 $b1 >> {a c d}`

Is there a function that can operate on lists on tcl?

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, you can't use brackets for list literals. Brackets are used for command substitution in Tcl.

Instead, use the list-making command, `list`

```
% set a1 [list a b c d e f]
a b c d e f
```

Or, more or less equivalently:

```
% set b1 {b f e}
b f e
```

There is no standard command to subtract one list from another. It's very easy to construct a filter, though.

You can filter out items in `a1` that are in `b1` by an `lmap` (list map) filter:

```
lmap item $a1 {
    if {$item ni $b1} {
        set item
    } else {
        continue
    }
}

# results in
a c d
```

The `if` command inside the `lmap` body determines if an item is *not in* (`ni`)`$b1`. If this is true, the value of the item becomes a part of the result. If it is false, the item is skipped.

In Tcl 8.5 and earlier, there is no `lmap`. In that case, one can copy-and-paste an ersatz `lmap` (works the same) into the code: link below.

Or, one can use `foreach` instead. It's a little messier but works.

```
set res {}
foreach item $a1 {
    if {$item ni $b1} {
        lappend res $item
    }
}

% set res
a c d
```

Documentation:
[continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an array. It's easy to add and remove elements

```
% foreach elem $a1 {set x($elem) 1}
% foreach elem $b1 {unset x($elem)}
% set result [array names x]
d a c
```

It's a pretty efficient approach too, only a single pass through each list.

Or use a dictionary to maintain the original insertion order:

```
% foreach elem $a1 {dict set y $elem 1}
% foreach elem $b1 {dict unset y $elem}
% set result [dict keys $y]
a c d
```

Comment: The limitation of course being that it will be difficult to have multiple elements with the same value (not in question).

Answer (score 2):

# with struct::set from tcllib

```
package require struct::set  
set a1 {a b c d e f}  
set b1 {b f e}  
struct::set difference $a1 $b1 

# result in  
d a c
```

Dokumentation:
[struct::set](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_set.html)

Comment: Please explain what you have done here, why did you choose struct::set.